# Next step to take in direct proof for one to one?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

This is from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications 
[image]

And the definition of strictly increasing.

[image]

Here is my work so far. [image]

I know that a direct proof involves making an assumption p, which in this case is that the function is strictly increasing, and then taking logical steps to reaching q, which is what I am trying to prove, in this case being  -function is one to one.

I wrote down the assumption and am trying to take steps to get from that to the one to one definition. From intuition, I understand that if it's strictly increasing, no function outputs can be the same so there are no conditions broken for one to one. But what step should i take next in the direct proof to express this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very nearly there. You just need to show that this function satisfies that definition.

So suppose that $f(x) = f(y)$ for some $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then can we have $x \neq y$? Why/why not? Use the property that $x \neq y \implies f(x) \neq f(y)$ for this function!

Comment: So you would assume that the function is strictly increasing and one to one?

Comment: No, you only assume that it is strictly increasing. The question is asking you to *prove* that it is then one-to-one.

Comment: Oh so you bring in the one to one definition as a logical step